# Will there be a blog post for Winter Bash 2019?

Tags: discussion, blog, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

In years past, there would be an announcement on the Stack Overflow Blog to launch Winter Bash.

- [WB 2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/19/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/)
- [WB 2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/12/16/winter-bash-2013-is-here/)
- [WB 2014](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/12/15/winter-bash-2014/)
- [WB 2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/14/announcing-winter-bash-2015/)
- [WB 2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/19/its-hat-season-announcing-winter-bash-2016/) (even includes [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U)!)
- [WB 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/)
- [WB 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/)

There doesn't seem to be any announcement so far regarding this year's Winter Bash. Will there be one this year?

Comment: I'm guessing there will be. Patience by friend, patience.

Comment: It's up now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is (and in about the same timing as last year).

## [‘Tis the Season for Hats! Join Us for Winter Bash 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/)